# What is the proper way to link CMake based project in Windows?

Tags: dll, linker, cmake, mingw

Finally, after whole day spent, I've made my CMake based project to successfully compile project on Windows(I've been developing it in Linux) and it even links well together, perfect isn't it? Now I launch the program and boom, it's not able to find dll libraries.

So, The problem:

I have CMake project with library and executable inside, that executable is using project's library. I also have many third party libraries in project. It compiles and links well. When I try to launch it it prints error that project's library wasn't found. I've copied it to the executable's directory. Now it prints that 3rd party library wasn't found, I've copied all of them to exe's dir. Now it prints that gcc's library wasn't found, so I've added C:\MinGW\bin to the path and now it launches fine.

But I feel it's not the proper way. I'd like to spare my teammates(new) of that pain of launching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either link everything statically, or add necessary `install()` calls into your CMakeLists.txt. Install all needed libs into the same directory and run executable from there.

If you want to run executable from CMAKE_BINARY_DIR, you can

```
set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )
set( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )
set( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )
```

This would make CMake to put linked binaries into the same dir.

As for gcc runtime - there is no other way except copying dll or linking statically.

Comment: There is no RPATH thing on Windows, AFAIK.

Comment: I think CMake should perform any help in that case, because when I try to use this project with Qt Creator, it won't launch. So CMake generator should tell how to launch program

Comment: CMake does not put the .dlls and executable in the same folder unless you tell it to do so.